# Custom prototype cells for Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, swift

I've been trying to figure out lately how to display data from a database in a particular way, as described on the picture below:

[image: UI]

Basically, as seen on many brand websites, I'd like to display each item from the database as rectangular cells, with a large image describing the item and 1 to 3 labels to put a title/subtitle/price tag.

I had no idea how to deal with it, to me it looked like creating some kind of table view with custom prototype cells, but I did not find any answers on the internet.

I'm sure the answer is quite simple but I can't figure it out unless doing entirely programmatically?

Comment: Look into [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html).

Comment: Like @jkaufman mentioned: UICollectionViewFlowLayout does what you want, out of the box.

Comment: Maybe take a look at a `UITableView` with multiple Sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as jkaufman said: `UICollectionView` is made for this purpose. You may create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` in Interface Builder with a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` as you illustrated. Be sure to give your custom `IUCollectionViewCell` a Reuse Identifier so you `UICollectionViewDataSource` can specify it.